# Django rest framework complex query

Tags: python, sql, django, rest

I have a database created. 
Each table has a model in django.

Given these 3 tables plus Customer primary key: Customer <-- Membership --> Club

How do I make a rest web service using django rest framework for showing data from these 3 tables?
Do I have to make a non-persistent model for these web service data?

I'm new to python, django and rest framework. By doing the following code I can query the 3 tables the way I want, although I want all 3 tables data (actually customer + club data) in one single result in order to send that result to rest framework so I can access it from URL and get json response

```
cId = Customer.objects.all().filter(pk=1)
memberships = Membership.objects.all().filter(customer_id=cId)
clubs = Club.objects.all().filter(pk__in=memberships)
```

I'm doing this in order to learn how to make a complex web service using rest in django.

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: You should provide the code of the models so we can give you an advice on how to build your query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set related_name on the ForeignKey fields? You can make backward search using the related name.
As I see you need a ManyToMany relation between Customer and Club. There comes the power of Django ORM. Take a look in the documentation for using Many-to-many relationships:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

If you can provide your models I'd give you concrete code examples for the queries.